# Pack a text file into an HTML file for download

Tags: html, static-pages

Instead of creating an additional text file and provide a link to it, can one embed some texts into an HTML file and provide a link to download it? The solution should work for a static website.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to base64 encode the file in the link, but you may want to do some cross-browser testing.

See [Create a file in memory for user to download, not through server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a static website and you want to be able to create a link to a HTML page that should be downloaded instead of "viewed" in the browser.

The only way I can think of to solve this is to use the [HTML 5 download attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a), like this:

```
<a href="somepage.html" download="somepage.html">Download</a>
```

Comment: The point is to embed some text to the html file so that there is no need to provide an additional file on the server for downloading.